# What does “Bs” (in Android Project Treble) mean?

Tags: android

According to [Dianne's clarification](https://groups.google.com/g/android-platform/c/RnvAtehYRz8/m/eq3vlpBNnr0J), we have learned that **Bn** is `Binder native` and **Bp**  is `Binder proxy`. But a new word, **Bs**, has been recently introduced in *Android Project Treble* since Android O.

From the source code of [hidl-gen](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/tools/hidl/utils/FQName.cpp;l=390;bpv=1;bpt=0), we only know that **Bs** has something related to `passthrough`, so, does it mean `stub`, `shim`, `skeleton` or something else? Would love a clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means 'binder same-process'. Source: I added this in https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/system/tools/hidl/+/274417